# Shiny: Dynamic colour (fill) input for ggplot

Tags: r, colors, shiny, shinyjs

i do need some help as the post: [Dynamic color input in shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594027/dynamic-color-input-in-shiny-server) does not give full answer to my problem.

I would like to have dynamic colour (fill) selection in my shiny app. I have prepared a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60, 2, 3), ncol=3))
dat <- melt(dat)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("select","Select:", choices=as.list(levels(dat$variable)), selected="X1",multiple =TRUE),
    uiOutput('myPanel'),
    plotOutput("plot"),
    downloadButton('downloadplot',label='Download Plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    cols <- reactive({
      lapply(seq_along(unique(input$select)), function(i) {
        colourInput(paste("col", i, sep="_"), "Choose colour:", "black")        
      })
    })

    output$myPanel <- renderUI({cols()})

    cols2 <- reactive({        
      if (is.null(input$col_1)) {
        cols <- rep("#000000", length(input$select))
      } else {
        cols <- unlist(colors())
      }
      cols})

    testplot <- function(){
      dat <- dat[dat$variable %in% input$select, ]
      ggplot(dat, aes(x=variable,y=value, fill=cols2()[1])) + geom_boxplot()}

    output$plot <- renderPlot({testplot()})

    output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
      filename ="plot.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
        print(testplot())
        dev.off()
      })
  }
))
```

I would like the user to choose fill colour of the boxplot. The number of colour widgets will appear according to number of selected variables in `selectizeInput("select"...`. Till this point everything is working perfectly, however going further i am not able to figure out how to apply this colour to the ggplot, etc...

Here are my questions:

1. How i can **connect the fill colour to ggplot** correctly
2. Can i make the **default colour of `colourInput()`** correspond to the default colour palette (not to one colour --> in my case is black)
3. Instead of **Choose colour** text in `colourInput(paste("col", i, sep="_"), "Choose colour:",` i would love to have the corresponding name (choosen variable from `selectizeInput`) of the variable (in this case X1, X2 and X3)
4. I would like as well to have a button which could **reset all** the choosen colours

Thank You all in advance and i hope this can be solved

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to be able to have a different color for a different box but they should have default values?

Comment: Yes exactly, i would like to have at the beginning default colours (like normally in ggplot when we choose fill argument as factor), but additionally if user wants to, he/she can change it (one or all of them). So instead of black colour in this function: `cols2 <- reactive({        
      if (is.null(input$col_1)) {
        cols <- rep("#000000",`, there will be first colour of default palette in ggplot, which is red. It can be any other palette, it does not matter to me, i just do not wanna have it all black or all as one colour at the start

Comment: All right , I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: Great!Thanks! :) I just wanted to point out that it has to be automatic assignment of colours (not variables like X1 = "red", X2 = "green"...), my orginal data has many variables thats why it is impossible to list all of them like that.

Comment: Replace `aes(x=variable,y=value, fill=cols2()[1])` with `aes_string(x="variable",y="value", fill=cols2()[1])` and you should be OK

Comment: @NJBurgo that cannot be the solution in my case, just for sake i have tried it and got 2 Errors:  `Error in [[: subscript out of bounds...` and `Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable...` and no plot at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are very nice and concrete questions and I'm glad to, hopefully, answer them :)

> 1. How i can connect the fill colour to ggplot correctly

In this case the best way, I think, is to fill boxes according to the `variable` (which is reactive) and to add a new layer `scale_fill_manual` in which you specify custom colours for different boxes. The number of colours has to be obviously equal to the number of levels of `variable`. This is probably the best way because you will always have a correct legend.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
          geom_boxplot() +
          scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

---

> 2. Can i make the default colour of colourInput() correspond to the default colour palette (not to one colour --> in my case is black)

Of course, you can do it.

First, you need to know the default colours for discrete variables that ggplot uses. To generate these colours we will use a function `gg_color_hue` found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette) nice discussion. I've changed its name to `gg_fill_hue` to follow a ggplot convention.

We can code everything within `renderUI` where we first specify the selected levels/variables. To get rid of unambiguity which would be caused due to dynamically (and possibly in a different order) generated widgets, we sort the names of levels/variables.

Then we generate appropriate number of default colours with `gg_fil_hue` and assign them to the appropriate widget.

To make things easier, we change the `IDs` of these widgets to `col` + "varname" which is given by `input$select`

```
output$myPanel <- renderUI({ 
      lev <- sort(unique(input$select)) # sorting so that "things" are unambigious
      cols <- gg_fill_hue(length(lev))

      # New IDs "colX1" so that it partly coincide with input$select...
      lapply(seq_along(lev), function(i) {
        colourInput(inputId = paste0("col", lev[i]),
                    label = paste0("Choose colour for ", lev[i]), 
                    value = cols[i]
        )        
      })
    })
```

---

> 3.Instead of Choose colour text in colourInput(paste("col", i, sep="_"), "Choose colour:", i would love to have the corresponding name (choosen variable from selectizeInput) of the variable (in this case X1, X2 and X3)

It is done in the code above as well - simple pasting.

---

Now, let's take a look at a very important issue that arises due to dynamical number of generated widgets. We have to set the colours of boxes according to a unique `colorInput` and there may by 1,2 or even 10 those inputs.

A very nice way of approaching this problem, I believe, is to create a character vector with elements specifying how we would normally access these widgets. In the example below this vector looks as follows: `c("input$X1", "input$X2", ...)`.

Then using non-standard evaluation (`eval`, `parse`) we can evaluate these inputs to get a vector with selected colours which we then pass to `scale_fill_manual` layer.

To prevent errors that may arise between selections, we will use the function `req´ to make sure that the length of the vector with colours is the same as the length of the selected levels/variables.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
        cols <- paste0("c(", paste0("input$col", sort(input$select), collapse = ", "), ")")
        # print(cols)
        cols <- eval(parse(text = cols))
        # print(cols)

        # To prevent errors
        req(length(cols) == length(input$select))

        dat <- dat[dat$variable %in% input$select, ]
        ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
          geom_boxplot() +
          scale_fill_manual(values = cols)

    })
```

---

> 4. I would like as well to have a button which could reset all the choosen colours

After defining the `actionButton` on the client side with an `ID="reset"` we create an observer that's going to update `colorInput`s.

Our goal is to return a list with `updateColourInput` with an appropriate parametrisation for each available `colourInput` widget.

We define a variable with all chosen levels/variables and generate an appropriate number of default colours. We again sort the vector to avoid ambiguity.

Then we use `lapply` and `do.call` to call a `updateColourInput` function with specified parameters that are given as a list.

```
observeEvent(input$reset, {
      # Problem: dynamic number of widgets
      # - lapply, do.call

      lev <- sort(unique(input$select))
      cols <- gg_fill_hue(length(lev))

      lapply(seq_along(lev), function(i) {
              do.call(what = "updateColourInput",
                      args = list(
                        session = session,
                        inputId = paste0("col", lev[i]),
                        value = cols[i]
                      )
              )
      })
    })
```

---

**Full Example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60, 2, 3), ncol=3))
dat <- melt(dat)

# Function that produces default gg-colours is taken from this discussion:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette
gg_fill_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("select", "Select:", 
                   choices = as.list(levels(dat$variable)), 
                   selected = "X1", 
                   multiple = TRUE), 
    uiOutput('myPanel'),
    plotOutput("plot"),
    downloadButton('downloadplot', label = 'Download Plot'),
    actionButton("reset", "Default colours", icon = icon("undo"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$myPanel <- renderUI({ 
      lev <- sort(unique(input$select)) # sorting so that "things" are unambigious
      cols <- gg_fill_hue(length(lev))

      # New IDs "colX1" so that it partly coincide with input$select...
      lapply(seq_along(lev), function(i) {
        colourInput(inputId = paste0("col", lev[i]),
                    label = paste0("Choose colour for ", lev[i]), 
                    value = cols[i]
        )        
      })
    })


    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      cols <- paste0("c(", paste0("input$col", sort(input$select), collapse = ", "), ")")
      # print(cols)
      cols <- eval(parse(text = cols))
      # print(cols)

      # To prevent errors
      req(length(cols) == length(input$select))

      dat <- dat[dat$variable %in% input$select, ]
      ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_boxplot() +
        scale_fill_manual(values = cols)

    })


    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      # Problem: dynamic number of widgets
      # - lapply, do.call

      lev <- sort(unique(input$select))
      cols <- gg_fill_hue(length(lev))

      lapply(seq_along(lev), function(i) {
        do.call(what = "updateColourInput",
                args = list(
                  session = session,
                  inputId = paste0("col", lev[i]),
                  value = cols[i]
                )
        )
      })
    })




    output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "plot.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        pdf(file, width = 12, height = 6.3)
        print(testplot())
        dev.off()
      })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thats an amazing answer! I am very grateful, it works like a charm! :)